# Why does Airflow best practice conflicts with PEP8 specifications?

Tags: python, airflow, pep8

The Airflow documentation has certain best practices, one of which is to [avoid top-level Python code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code). This is in direct contrast with the PEP8 specifications. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Answer: people & groups are entitled to opinions which don't always align with one another. Can you cite a specific passage of PEP8 you feel is directly contradictory to the best practice recommendation you linked?

Comment: Also important to keep in mind that Python and PEP8 by extension are intended for application in a ***MUCH*** more vast array of use cases than Airflow is, and thus have to make those considerations when electing to include or exclude any guidance therein.

Comment: Does this statement from the linked documentation for Airflow not answer your question? "*You should avoid writing the top level code which is not necessary to create Operators and build DAG relations between them. This is because of the design decision for the scheduler of Airflow and the impact the top-level code parsing speed on both performance and scalability of Airflow.*" If not, what do you feel is not addressed?

Comment: @esqew It does answer my question, however, someone I know was arguing that since this is in direct contrast with PEP8, we should avoid it. I tried explaining that if we do top-level imports in Airflow, the DAG takes more time to be parsed. But I wanted a more educated explanation.

Comment: seems reasonable to use the most specific best practices, which for Airflow scripts would be the Airflow best practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very introduction of PEP8 says that project-specific guidelines take precedence over PEP8:

> Many projects have their own coding style guidelines. In the event of any conflicts, such project-specific guides take precedence for that project.

So, technically, Airflow does not conflict with PEP8 :) Also, just a few paragraphs later:

> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is the most important.

> However, know when to be inconsistent – sometimes style guide recommendations just aren’t applicable. When in doubt, use your best judgment. Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don’t hesitate to ask!

The last paragraph is fairly critical: "sometimes style guide recommendations just aren’t applicable." In the case of Airflow, there is a very legitimate reason why top-level DAG code should be avoided, and it has nothing to do with style: all top-level Python code is executed when the DAG is parsed. Since DAGs are parsed very frequently ([every 30 seconds by default](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#min-file-process-interval)), this can cause drastic performance degradation to the scheduler / DAG parsing process.

Import statements at the top of a file are top-level code, too, so if a module takes a long time to import (e.g. numpy), then it could adversely impact the scheduler, hence the advice to import these modules within the context of a task, but the vast majority of modules can be imported into Airflow DAGs at the top of the DAG file in compliance with PEP8 without issue. Honestly, I don't even think numpy is a problem, so I've opened a [PR to update this section of the documentation with a more pragmatic example and description](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/35097).